# How to initialize key,value pair in dictionary with lambda expression?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, lambda

I have a dictionary where key is a tuple (class,word). I want to initialize the value of dictionary for a particular class, irrespective of the word to a particular default value.
Eg: dict = defaultdict(lambda : -1.0)

dict [('A', any word here)] = some constant value according to lambda expression

Here of the tuple ('A', any word here)- A is the class while "any word here" can be any random unknown word.
This was my attempt, but am unable to figure out the correct way:
dict = defaultdict(lambda tag, x: some_constant)).

How to I make x a placeholder that might come in its place?

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, you want a dictionary to have a default value that depends on part of the key.  If so, I think this does what you want:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        class_, word = key
        self[key] = class_ # Replace this with what you want
        return self[key]
```

Now, `MyDict` behaves just as a normal dictionary except that missing values are filled in according to the custom function which you will have to adjust to your needs.

For example:

```
In [22]: d = MyDict()
In [23]: d[(int, 'delta')]
Out[23]: int    
In [24]: d[(str, 'gamma')]
Out[24]: str    
In [25]: d
Out[25]: {(str, 'gamma'): str, (int, 'delta'): int}
```

Be careful of one point: when you use the `get` attribute to a dictionary with a missing key, it will *not* call `__missing__`.  Instead, it will return whatever you specify as the second argument to `get` and that defaults to `None`.

#### The problem with `defaultdict`

One might like `defaultdict` to behave as you want with:

```
dict = defaultdict(lambda tag, x: some_constant))
```

However, this will not work because the `defaultdict` constructor does not accept arguments.  With `defaultdict`, the default value must be the same regardless of key.